# Eiffel: setting a constant with reference to other class constant

Tags: eiffel

How to set a constant refering to another class constant in Eiffel?

Something like that doesn't compile unfortunately

```
Default_log_level: like {MY_LOGGER}.log_level = {MY_LOGGER}.Log_level_info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant attributes cannot be defined using other constant attributes in the current version of Eiffel.

Comment: :-( is it planned to support it ?

Comment: @Pipo This is being discussed, but there is no draft, so I would not assume it would be supported in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Constant attributes can only be made of a manifest constant, but a possible workaround could be to use frozen once functions:

```
frozen Default_log_level: INTEGER
    once
       Result := {MY_LOGGER}.Log_level_info
    ensure
        definition: Result = {MY_LOGGER}.Log_level_info
    end
```

`frozen` means that it cannot be redefined in descendant classes (like constant attributes).

Unfortunately, the type of `once` functions cannot rely  on anchored types, hence the use of `INTEGER` instead of `like {MY_LOGGER}.log_level`.

And finally, the drawback with this solution is that it cannot be used where constant attributes are expected (e.g. in `inspect` instructions).

Comment: I would suggest adding the postcondition `class` so that the once function can be used in non-object calls.