# Eiffel: best way to create a redefinable "constant"

Tags: eiffel

As mentioned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420105/eiffel-setting-a-constant-with-reference-to-other-class-constant), there is no way to define a constant which I can redefine into a descendant.

In many of my cases, I'd like to have a constant which I can redefine. The alternatives I see to **avoid a creation on each consultation**  which doesn't make sense would be

### That's not doable

```
class A

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING = "some A value"

end -- Class


class B

inherit
    B
        redefine
            Default_value
        end

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING = "some B value"

end -- Class
```

### Alternative with once instance_free

```
class A

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING
        once
            Result := "some A value"
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end

end -- Class


class B

inherit
    B
        redefine
            Default_value
        end

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING
        once
            Result := "some B value"
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end

end -- Class
```

As far as I understand, the once wouldn't be created with B value as the A class value would be taken

### Alternative with attribute

```
class A

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING
        attribute
            Result := "some A value"
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end

end -- Class


class B

inherit
    B
        redefine
            Default_value
        end

feature -- Access

    Default_value: STRING
        attribute
            Result := "some B value"
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end

end -- Class
```

Would it be the only and good practice to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of 3 mentioned possibilities, only instance-free once functions can be used because

- constants are frozen and, therefore, cannot be redefined;
- instance-free attributes are not supported.

One more way is to use regular functions with manifest once strings to guarantee that result is always the same:

```
class A feature
    default_value: STRING
        do
            Result := once "some A value" -- Note the modifier "once".
        ensure
            instance_free: class
            constant: Result = default_value -- Ensure the Result is constant.
        end
end
```

However, there seems to be no particular benefit compared to instance-free once functions. (I would still keep the postcondition `constant` to avoid erroneous redeclaration of the feature.)

**Edit.** Some details for the example above:

1. At run-time, regular manifest strings of the form `"foo"` create a new string object every time they are evaluated. Once manifest strings of the form `once "foo"` create a new string object only for the first time instead. On subsequent evaluation, they produce the same object that was computed earlier.
2. Postcondition `Result = f` of a query `f` (the example uses `default_value` instead of `f`) ensures that the second call to `f` produces the same object as the first call. Indeed, in expression `Result = f`, `Result` refers to the object computed by the feature. The call `f` refers to the object computed by the second call to the feature. So, whenever we call `f`, it produces the same object. (Ideally, we would explicitly require that the third, fourth, etc. calls to the feature also produce the same object. However, this is beyond expressive power of the language. Formally, the equality of all results produced by `f` could be proved by induction.)

Comment: Thx, I'm stuck on once "inline" and the semantic of `Result = default_value` (seems obvious for me, what could be the case of not being true?) could you tell a bit more about these 2 new concepts for me or point me out some doc about it?

Comment: @Pipo I've added explanations to the answer.